# Is there any sense to have a DB migration system for a NoRel DB?

Tags: node.js, database-migration, nosql

I'm working with node js and I have to perform a first setup of my Database. I'm going to use a noSQL db engine.

I have to perform my create table, and I'm thinking it would be nice to have a migration system to keep track of the structure changes. Or maybe just even the initial db structure.

But I'm also thinking that noSQL is mostly schemaless. (Apart main indexes)

So I'm wondering if I'm looking after something with not much sense, or if there's around already an approach like the above...

Comment: Interesting question. Regarding Mongo, it seems pretty useless as you don't have a schema, at all. On the other hand, if you consider that your data get mapped into domain models developed in type-safe languages, it is pretty important to have a consistent structure. For such cases, a tool that keeps track of property changes, or differing data types for the same property path etc, could be useful for certain use cases.

Comment: At this time I'm looking at DynamoDB, and also I'm thinking about if I need to alter indexes, not just properties